# select records from table given as column name. Dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I've searched some topics here but there have not been any answers which I need.
I want to make a query where I will join a table basing on the column name in the first table.

I'm using sql server so it would be appreciate if someone know solution for this technology.

Here is a sample what I wanna do:

**Tables**:

```
main_table
----------
id | tab      | another_col
----------------------
1 | product_x | abcd
2 | product_y | efgh


table_product_x
----------------------
id | yyy
----------------------
1 | simple_yyy_value1


table_product_y
----------------------
id | yyy
----------------------
2 | simple_yyy_value4
```

**Output**:

```
product_x | simple_yyy_value1 | abcd
product_y | simple_yyy_value4 | efgh
```

**Query**(*sketch*)

```
select tab, yyy, another_col from main_table
join 'table_'+tab xxx on xxx.id = main_table.id
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add some sample data for your tables and the expected output to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build this using `union all` and some dynamic SQL.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
declare @Pattern nvarchar(100)

set @Pattern = 'select ''[TABLE_NAME]'' as TableName, yyy from table_[TABLE_NAME]'

select @SQL = stuff((select ' union all '+replace(@Pattern, '[TABLE_NAME]', tab)
                     from main_table
                     for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 11, '')

exec (@SQL)
```

The statement executed will look something like this:

```
select 'product_x' as TableName, yyy 
from table_product_x 
union all 
select 'product_y' as TableName, yyy 
from table_product_y
```

Comment: Nice solution, but how can I make a join in this select? Look the output example in my question.

Comment: @nosbor I don't understand. This will give you the result you want. What do you need to join against? Please update your question.

Comment: Your query gives table name in first column instead of tab column from main_table. I updated my question to highlight what I wanna do. See main_table, sample query and output.

Comment: @nosbor I updated the answer. You just have to modify the `@Pattern` variable.